# why I can't get value from controller scope with ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I will show you the code on jsbin. 
the issue is : $scope.name never show,thank you

http://jsbin.com/buwij/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">
  <a href="#/you">go to</a>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="you.html">
    {{name}}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var test = angular.module('test',[]);
test.config(function($rootProvider){
  $rootProvider
    .when('/you',{
      templateUrl: 'you.html',
      controller: 'youCtrl'
    });
});

test.controller('youCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'you';
});
```

Comment: its `$routeProvider` not `$rootProvider` and you need to add the `ngRoute` dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a quick [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyHMIgpzn0nk8NoXxqON?p=preview)

You were missing the `ngRoute` dependency and script on your module

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>`

and you need to setup your module like so `var test = angular.module('test',['nRoute']);`

and its `$routeProvider` not `$rootProvider` simple spelling error.